# Подписи к картинке в html

Tags: html, css

Как реализовать такие подписи к картинке? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исходная картинка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исходный html

```html
<div>
<figure>
<p><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBbdw.jpg"/></p>
<figcaption>Посмотрите как прекрасен мир без VR- очков</figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как вариант, можно использовать `position: absolute`. Также, тег `p` был удален, так как он не предназначен для размещения изображений.

```css
.image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.image-wrapper img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.image-caption {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ff000075;
  bottom: 4px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <figure class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://mtdata.ru/u28/photo96CE/20466331848-0/original.jpg" />
    <figcaption class="image-caption">Посмотрите как прекрасен мир без VR- очков</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Здесь задана ширина в пикселях - частный случай, нужно, чтобы figure всегда был по ширине картинки.

Comment: Внес исправления, теперь там ширина 100%